How does Christianity view compassion?
How does Christianity view compassion?
According to Christianity, does compassion mean to "suffer together", as in this Google search result?

What is the true meaning of compassion? Compassion literally means “to suffer together.” Among emotion researchers, it is defined as the feeling that arises when you are confronted with another's suffering and feel motivated to relieve that suffering.  Compassion is not the same as empathy or altruism, though the concepts are related.

Does the Bible also teach that compassion mean to "suffer together" or does compassion also have another implicit meaning?
EDITED and this section moved to answer as below

I think you'll have to edit to be about what the bible teaches about compassion (though this is still kind of broad) or a particular denomination. As stated it seems very broad and doesn't express much of a question. Do you expect Christianity's view to be different than the general term? why?

Welcome to the site.  This can potentially be a good question, but 1) you need to cite your quote; 2) you need to be more specific, such as ask how is Christ's passion related to our compassions to others.  One great lecture talking about how Christians should be compassionate following Jesus's example is in this lecture: The Cross as Revelation of the Divine Life in Gregory the Great

Your definition is obsolete, according to the Oxford English Dictionary, which defines 'compassion' as The feeling or emotion, when a person is moved by the suffering or distress of another, and by the desire to relieve it; pity that inclines one to spare or to succour..

@NigelJ, the "it is defined as …" is more or less the same as you quoted, so how is it obsolete? ¶ As for the original literal meaning, Online Etymology Dictionary says: "… literally "a suffering with another," … from Late Latin compassionem … from com "with, together" … + pati "to suffer" …".

@RayButterworth I refer you to the entry in the Oxford English Dictionary to which I gave a link. The first meaning listed is that which is obsolete.

@NigelJ refers to a now obsolete definition: "The compassion of sense 1 was between equals or fellow-sufferers; this is shown towards a person in distress by one who is free from it, who is, in this respect, his or her superior.". The OP nowhere uses this definition, so how can you claim that "Your definition is obsolete"?

@RayButterworth The OP refers to 'to suffer together' (which is the obsolete meaning (according to the OED). I have not commented on what 'emotion researchers' have to say.

@NigelJ, the OP says "Compassion literally means …", not that it does mean that. Every dictionary that provides an etymology for the word says the same thing. ¶ "Husband" literally means "house owner" and "volatile" literally means "to fly". Those are their literal meanings, not their definitions. To refer to them with "Your definition is obsolete" would be inappropriate.

Brother @depperm I had updated my question. Kindly and feel free to comment, up/down vote.

Brother @RayButterworth I had updated my question. Kindly and feel free to comment, up/down vote.

Brother @NigelJ I had updated my question. Kindly and feel free to comment, up/down vote.

Brother @GratefulDisciple I had updated my question. Kindly and feel free to comment, up/down vote.

@BananaTech I was trying to help you by making your question more understandable by the community.  You changed "Christian growth" back to "Christianity growth".  What are you trying to say?  "Christianity growth" doesn't make sense.  Who is growing?  In the verse, the one who "may be perfect and complete, lacking in nothing" is a Christian person.

To @NigelJ and others: please consider retracting "Needs more detail" close vote, or provide feedback after this edit.

@GratefulDisciple Thanks for the edit. Much blessed.

@GratefulDisciple On the contrary, I think the question is  now more confused and muddled than before. I am not being unkind ; I am being academically truthful. The proper examination of scripture needs to be orderly and constructive and disciplined if it is to be fruitful. Asking the wrong questions or asking imprecise questions does not lead to an advance in knowledge.

@BananaTech Why are you quoting and focusing on those verses from James rather than some of the many verses in the Bible that actually discuss compassion directly?

@curiousdannii because other quote not direct explanation or very surface .. compassion must come with an action rather than feeling alone .. found this is closest one personally . I m still new to Christianity  .. why not attempt to answer if u know an answer. Much blessed

"James 1:2-4 (ESV) has this to say about Suffering" — But the word "suffering" doesn't appear in James 1. ¶ The original meaning of "suffering" is "allow to occur or continue, refrain from hindering, fail to prevent or suppress", as in Luke 18:16, "Suffer little children to come unto me, and forbid them not". Is "allow" your intended meaning here? ¶ There seems to be a lot of confusion in this question caused by inflating the multiple meanings that some words have.

What is being asked isn't clear. There are seven distinct questions here, where there should be only one. The item is far too ambiguous and chaotic.  It should be rewritten so that it presents the facts and then asks one single question about them. And that question should be an objective one, not soliciting subjective opinions, as does "would it better if …".

@RayButterworth Let's be more helpful toward someone new to Christianity and to the Bible and look at the central concern phrased in a human way rather than theological way.  The "suffering" here is clearly a certain kind of human experience and while citing James 1:2-4 is not the best, but respecting the OP's perspective he wants to link whatever latent there (which is a community undergoing trials, which then produce "suffering") with the practice of "compassion" which is huge in Buddhism.

@RayButterworth Also, I don't see "seven distinct question", but wanting to know Christianity's description of "compassion", and when OP was pushed (in the comments) to make the Q a more Biblical / theological question, he then offered that not-so-relevant verse, but STILL able to make the question more specific by offering his own understanding.  Yes, this question is rather subjectively formed and can be improved (which I just did), but I think there is still an objective core to it, that Christianity should be able to answer objectively.

@BananaTech "compassion must come with an action rather than feeling alone"  Christianity also teaches this, especially in Jesus's parable of the Good Samaritan where the Samaritan does something (taking the robbery victim to the inn at his expense).  In the lecture I linked above, Prof. Jordan Wales presented his paper connecting Jesus's suffering on the cross as the Good Samaritan compassionating with all of us.

@GratefulDisciple thanks for edit and answering. Why not brother answers here. Many of my fellow Christians would like to know and I have difficulty to answer them. A person can b more effectively walk the spirit and sharing the Gospel too I believe if they understand what is true meaning of compassion.

@BananaTech I agree with you that the true meaning of compassion is important to know and after that, to practice.  I'll be using that lecture / paper for my own answer to be written  in the next few days.  In the meantime you can listen to the lecture first, or read the paper.  That is coming from the "reputable source" asked for in your bounty.

@GratefulDisciple thank U so much. Much blessed brother

@GratefulDisciple says "I think there is still an objective core to it, that Christianity should be able to answer objectively" — Agreed, but I don't think the question, no matter how much it's been improved, states it understandably. ¶ I think, but could be wrong, it is: ""Compassion" means "trying to alleviate someone else's bad experience", but originally derives from "sharing that bad experience".
The latter could improve one's strength, the former could improve one's character.
Which definition does the Bible use and how does that compare with mainstream Christianity's view?".

@RayButterworth The OP possibly has a misinformed point of view, so it is the answer's job to correct it by providing the Biblical definition and/or the Christian definition in light of God's incarnation in Jesus Christ who is compassionate and who is supremely objective.  Why don't you provide an answer?  If it turns out that the answer depends on a branch of Christianity, then we can ask the OP to scope it.  My own answer would be along the line of Prof. Jordan Wales's definition, which in turn is the Patristic definition that may be carried to the Middle Ages.

During my early years as a Christian, I listened to the four gospel accounts being read out on cassette tapes (yes, that was a long time ago) and what impressed me the most was the number of times I heard “and Jesus had compassion on them.”   Jesus Christ, the Son of God exemplified all the Father’s attributes, including His compassion.  Compassion is a deep empathy for those who are in need. To be compassionate is to have mercy towards others, to feel sympathy, and to have pity. It moves us to action, to show love for others in a Christ-like way.

When Jesus saw His friends weeping at the grave of Lazarus, He felt compassion for them and wept alongside them (John 11:33-35). Moved with compassion for the suffering of others, Jesus healed the large crowds who came to Him (Matthew 14:14), as well as individuals who sought His healing (Mark 1:40-41). When He saw the large crowds as sheep without a shepherd, His compassion led Him to teach them the things the false shepherds of Israel had abandoned. The priests and scribes were proud and corrupt; they despised the common people and neglected them, but Jesus had compassion on them, and He taught and loved them.


“The Lord is gracious and full of compassion” (Psalm 111:4, NKJV). By nature, He is imbued with tenderness, kindness, and compassion (Psalm 119:156; Joel 2:13; 2 Corinthians 1:3; James 5:11). God’s compassion is closely related to His love and mercy. Compassion is a deep empathy for those who are in need.
Source

Because we are helpless Christ Jesus became one of us so that He could rescue us (John 1:14; Philippians 2:6–7).  He experienced human sorrow, pain, and temptation (Hebrews 4:15).  He is the physical embodiment of compassion.

The most profound and extravagant expression of God’s compassion is in Jesus Christ, His Son, whom He sent to be our Savior (Luke 1:78–79). Jesus’ ministry was filled with compassion: “When he saw the crowds, he had compassion on them because they were confused and helpless, like sheep without a shepherd” (Matthew 9:36, NLT). Moved by compassion, Jesus healed the sick (Matthew 14:14; 20:34; Mark 8:2), comforted the grieving (Luke 7:13; 8:50; John 11:33–35), fed the hungry (Matthew 15:32), offered rest to the weary and burdened (Matthew 11:28–29), and ministered salvation to the lost (Matthew 9:36; John 8:10–11).


Because our God is gracious, righteous, and full of compassion (Psalm 116:5), He calls His chosen children to clothe themselves “with compassion, kindness, humility, gentleness and patience” toward one another (Colossians 3:12). The apostle Paul urged believers to “be kind and compassionate to one another, forgiving each other, just as in Christ God forgave you” (Ephesians 4:32). Jesus is our perfect model to follow (Luke 10:36–37; John 13:34; 17:18; Philippians 2:1), and is our ever-present helper, equipping and filling us with the divine power and inspiration to love others with His compassion.
Source

Christian compassion is more than simply feeling sorry for others.  The principle is that not only must we love God will our whole being, but we must also love our neighbour.  And who is our neighbour?  It is more than our Christian brothers and sisters.  It is more than our family and friends.  Our neighbour embraces every person we come into contact with.  Christian compassion will motivate us to action to help others, materially or physically and also spiritually, both within the Church and beyond.
These three Bible verses give us the Christian view of compassion:

Colossians 3:12-13  Put on then, as God’s chosen ones, holy and beloved, compassionate hearts, kindness, humility, meekness, and patience, bearing with one another and, if one has a complaint against another, forgiving each other; as the Lord has forgiven you, so you also must forgive.


Galatians 6:2  Bear one another's burdens, and so fulfill the law of Christ.


2 Corinthians 1:3-4  Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Father of mercies and God of all comfort, who comforts us in all our affliction, so that we may be able to comfort those who are in any affliction, with the comfort with which we ourselves are comforted by God.

Yes, Christians can expect to suffer together, just as our Lord and Saviour suffered.  And Christians are called to help one another so we will be built up in the faith.  As we talk about the love of God, we must practice what we preach, regardless of personal cost.

The Bible is (or, should be!) the most authoritative source for Christians. Using as my 'reputable source' Robert Young's "Analytical Concordance" for the Authorised Version, I have learned the following:
The Old Testament has 22 verses using several different Hebrew words for 'compassion'. Two of them include the meaning of "to pity" and "to spare". One means "tender mercies". One means being full of "compassionate mercies". Another means to "love, pity, be merciful". Christians would learn a lot about compassion from studying those 22 verses, for God also shows such compassion. Such an understanding would follow on in to the New Testament.
There are 20 instances of compassion being written in the New Testament.
One Greek word is spla, meaning "deepest yearning" ('bowels' being the old-fashioned English word implying deepest feeling). Matthew 9:36; 14:14; 18:27. Mark 1:41; 6:34
A very similar meaning, having deepest yearning, occurs in Matthew 15:32; 20:34. Mark 8:2; 9:22. Luke 7:13; 10:33; 15:20.
Another meaning is with the Greek word eleeo, to "show mildness, kindness", and is found in Matthew 18:33 and Mark 5:19, then Jude vs. 22.
The word that has the sense of suffering compassionately with others is in 1 Peter 3:8. It is also in Hebrews 10:34. This is the word sumpatheo.
Undoubtedly, for Christians to suffer together in love will build them up in faith. It goes beyond mere theory, or mere feelings, and entails living out this quality.
EDIT in response to comment: A fulsome answer would go into all 42 verses where compassion is involved, and, yes, the Hebrew word rachum is powerful in showing what is involved in God's compassions, but I do not see that word used in Psalm 103:8, A.V. It reads, "The Lord is merciful and gracious, slow to anger, and plenteous in mercy." Reading on to verse 14 gives the full measure of God's wonderful dealings with sinful humanity, so I would suggest all those verses need to be grasped to see how high above the heavens are God's mercies to us. I would never single out 'compassion' as "one of the most essential of God's characteristics". They are all on a par.
And, as another answer has succinctly pointed out, the greatest proof of God's compassion towards sinners was in sending his beloved, only-begotten Son to suffer and die for sinners. Of course, that supreme example involves all of God's characteristics, not just one. Christ entered compassionately into our desperate, doomed situation, to deliver us. And that should be the uppermost view Christians have of God's compassion.

In terms of what I think the question is asking, notice that in almost all scriptural cases, the meaning is "trying to alleviate someone else's bad experience" and is not simply "sharing that bad experience"; it means changing the actual situation rather than comforting within the situation.

In addition to the Greek words would you identify the Hebrew words used?  Is one of them rachum used in verses like the famous Ps 103:8 to signal one of the most essential of God's characters?

@GratefulDisciple   Thank you.  I have responded with an Edit to my answer.

@RayButterworth  Thank you. Those points are valid.

For the most fundamental answer to this question I would look to the Lord Jesus himself. He did not merely suffer with us but He also suffered for us.
Though he was not subject to death, He took on flesh in order to suffer death for all men, thus freeing them by His own suffering.
Given this greatest show of compassion we should not shy away from the thought of suffering with our brothers nor of rejoicing with them.

Compassion isn't a term that either scriptures or any major sects of Christianity defines in a unique way as far as I am aware. That said, you can review the words in the original Hebrew and Greek to see the range of meaning these words can convey.
In Hebrew, the word רַחֲמִים (ra-cha-mim) can be translated as: mercy, compassion, or womb. The connection between compassion and the womb evokes the image of the love of a mother concerned for her child; it is action motivated by deep emotion and concern for another.
In Greek, the word σπλαγχνίζομαι (splagchnizomai) can be translated as: to be moved in the inward parts, to feel compassion.
Strong's Dictionary (linked above) provides this additional bit of information:

Cognate: 4697 splagxnízomai – "from splanxna, 'the inward parts,' especially the nobler entrails – the heart, lungs, liver, and kidneys. These gradually came to denote the seat of the affections" (WS, 111). See 4698 (splangxnon).

Once more, the word being translated as compassion from the Greek communicates this idea of being moved by the "seat of the affections" - by something internal. Compassion is an emotional response reflecting our affections for another.

James 1:2-4 (ESV) has this to say about Suffering:

Count it all joy, my brothers, when you meet trials of various kinds,
for you know that the testing of your faith produces steadfastness.
And let steadfastness have its full effect, that you may be perfect
and complete, lacking in nothing.

The Suffering,
> When you meet trials of various kinds --> (Implies) Testing from God
> for you know that the testing of your faith produces steadfastness. --> (Implies) Learning or Putting Faith into Action rather than Sola Fide
> that you may be perfect and complete, lacking in nothing. --> (Implies) Growth in a Christian together with bonding of love
In other words, would Christians conceive "compassion" to also include the implicit meaning of "learning and growing together"
instead of "suffering together". Challenges make you stronger everyday. God wants you to be stronger
or as per @Anne answer
"Christians to suffer together in love will build them up in faith. It goes beyond mere theory, or mere feelings, and entails living out this quality."

Why do you think this verse is central for understanding the Christian view of compassion, when it doesn't directly discuss compassion at all?

@curiousdannii because it's related to suffering. Suffering related to bond of love. love is compassion. Let me know if not making sense

Those are your theories, but you've given nothing that suggests most Christians would agree with you, and it's a big flaw to derive your theology from a single passage that doesn't even refer directly to compassion while ignoring all the other passages which do discuss it directly.

@curiousdannii no issue . U are welcome to disagree or contribute anything here. Well, I m trying to map Bible to Neuroscience A prominent neuroevolutionary framework grounds compassion in the neurobiology of the mammalian caregiving system. Accordingly, it has been suggested that the oxytocinergic system, which plays a central role in parental caregiving and bonding, provides the neurobiological foundation for compassion towards strangers. U can Google this

@curiousdannii nevertheless, I m still learning. U r welcome to share anything here. Much blessed
